Calculating the work to empty a vessel
I need to calculate the work needed to empty the vessel defined by the curves:
$$
    f_O(x) = 12 - \sqrt{12^2-1/.1^2(x-3)^2}, 3\leq x\leq 4.2\\
    g_O(x) = -1/25(x-3)(x+3), 0\leq x\leq 3\\
    f_I(x) = 12.5 - \sqrt{12^2-1/.1^2(x-3)^2}, 3\leq x\leq 4.1989579\\
    g_I(x) = -1/25(x-3)(x+3) + 0.5, 0\leq x\leq 3$$
That is rotated about the y-axis.  Assuming the vessel is completely filled with water I tried using the integrals below to solve for the work needed to remove the water:
$$
W = 9.8\left(\int_{0}^{12-43/50}1*y*\pi*F_I(y)^2dy + 2\int_{12-43/50}^{11.5}1*y*\pi*\left(\frac{F_I(y)-G_I(y)}{2}\right)^2dy\right)$$
I assumed the vessel is filled with water, the xy-units are in centimeters, and I used 1 $g/cm^3$ for the density of water.
where $F_I(y)$ and $G_I(y)$ are the equations $f_I(x)$ and $g_I(x)$ solved for $x$, specifically:
$$F_I(y) =3+\sqrt{.1^2*(12^2-(12.5-y)^2)}, 1/2\leq y\leq 12\\
G_I(y) = \sqrt{9-25(y-0.5)}, 1/2\leq y\leq 43/50$$
However, when I try to compute this integral with my calculator I get an error (non-real result).  I think the problem is with the bounds of integration, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Hi man, could you introduce more the context, especially the physical environment of your vessel and the mean which with you're emptying it (pump, just truned upside down) you know like concrete dynamic of it.

The context would be pump the vessel empty.  I'm approaching this more from the mathematical perspective less so from a physics/engineering perspective.

Yes, bu the way you do it, with or without viscosity, depending of your pump change many things.

Assume a theoretical situation where pump that operates without friction or and liquid has zero viscosity.
